# How is string.find implemented in CPython?

Tags: python

I was wondering if the 'find' method on strings was implemented with a linear search, or if python did something more sophisticated. The Python documentation doesn't discuss implementation details, so http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html is of no help. Could someone please point me to the relevant source code?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The comment on the implementation has the following to say:

> fast search/count implementation,
>   based on a mix between boyer-moore
>   and horspool, with a few more bells
>   and whistles on the top.
>
> for some more background, see: http://effbot.org/zone/stringlib.htm

—https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/stringlib/fastsearch.h#L5

Comment: Couldn't edit question: Broken link. Current one is: https://web.archive.org/web/20201107074620/http://effbot.org/zone/stringlib.htm

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to find it in Objects/stringlib/find.h, although the real code is in fastsearch.h.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the algorithm used originates from [Boyer-Moore-Horspool algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore%E2%80%93Horspool_algorithm)

Answer (score 0):

Since [this 2021 commit](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/73a85c4e1da42db28e3de57c868d24a089b8d277), if the strings are long enough, left-to-right string search is implemented via [Crochemore and Perrin's Two-Way string searching algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-way_string-matching_algorithm) (1991). It has linear time in the worst case.