# How to write in with its fundamental brute steps?

Tags: python, arrays, search

I was looking to solve the [longest consecutive sequence question on Leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-consecutive-sequence/description/) and this is the provided solution.

The question lies in the inner loop right after  `# how to rewrite this part without in?`

```
class Solution:
    def longestConsecutive(self, nums):
        longest_streak = 0

        for num in nums:
            current_num = num
            current_streak = 1

            # how to rewrite this part without in?
            while current_num + 1 in nums:
                current_num += 1
                current_streak += 1

            longest_streak = max(longest_streak, current_streak)

        return longest_streak
```

I wrote a version that of the inner loop doesn't use `in` like this.

```
while j < n and i != j:
    if nums[j] == currentSequenceNumber + 1:
        currentSequenceLength += 1
        currentSequenceNumber = nums[j]
    j += 1
```

I realized after running `pdb` that this approach would only work for 2 consecutive numbers but not more. How could I rewrite my original portion to keep checking without using `in`. I have a feeling that `in` using a similar approach as `find` when it comes to sequences. I have seen [this link for find in strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681649/how-is-string-find-implemented-in-cpython) but it is not the brute force approach that I would like to write out.

I think seeing this how this can be rewritten would clarify why the space complexity is `O(n^3)` as the solution states. I currently can't understand why with their explanation.

Comment: Do you know what `in` does? Do you understand that it is O(n) when looking if some item is `in` a list? What is your question exactly?

Comment: I understand what in does. It will search the entire list for the item in O(n) time. That's not the issue. What I would like to see is the code written out without using `in`.

Comment: Could you make an answer with code?

Answer (score 0):

Would write this as a comment but I lack rep (!). I think time complexity of `in` depends on the structure it is applied to, for example if it is done on a list it has to search every item in the list in series but for a set or dict then it can lookup by hash.

So I can't tell you how to write `in` unless I know what type `nums` is (a good use case for type hints here also). However:

1. list: average O(n)
2. set: average O(1) worst O(n)

BTW, sets are awesome and a great reason to use Python. Oftentimes people use lists all over the place and wonder why their code doesn't scale...

EDIT: due to stupid rules I still can't comment, so leaving this here. No, I'm not going to write a for, if, break loop for you, it's absolutely trivial.

Comment: I do get that it works in O(n) time. What I would like to see is how that inner loop would need to be written without the use of `in` and still get the longest consecutive subsequence that is longer than length 2.